# Appeal to reopen a recently closed question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

How do I convince/persuade/implore/etc those volunteer policemen and policewomen of this site for clemency on this question titled [Can centuar walk down stairs?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22204/can-centuar-walk-down-stairs?) I shall invoke the right to bribe... just kidding but seriously upwards of 150 reputations what says you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked question is currently on hold as "unclear what you are asking".

Begging, bribing, etc. isn't going to make the question any more clear. (In fact, neither is posting on it on Meta.)

Instead, you should follow the advice in the "put on hold" box.

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Aify, JDługosz, Green, SJuan76, o.m. 1 hour ago
>
> **Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.** As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, **please edit the question.**

(my emphasis)

Normally when voting to close, it would be courteous to also add one or more comments pointing out what the problem/s with the question is/are (questions that get put on hold without any comments actually show up in the moderator flag queue). However, two things about your question stand out to me like a sore thumb:

- The question title needs to match (and summarize) the question body. As it stands, the question title seems to be about one thing (whether centaurs can walk down stairs), and the question body seems to be about another (the reason for inventing stairs). With so little to go on, that can certainly justify closing as unclear. A few sentences is *very rarely* enough to ask a question that is specific enough that specific answers can be given.
- I fail to see the worldbuilding component in your question; it looks more like the beginnings of a rant or a flamebait, intended more to provoke discussion than to seek specific answers. That would be reason to close as primarily opinion-based, or possibly as simply "not about worldbuilding".

In my opinion, these two points need fixing before the question can be eligible for reopening.